# How to combine LSTM and CNN in timeseries classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, time-series

Most commonly CNN is used when there are images as data. However, I have seen that CNN are sometines used for timeseries. Therefore, I tried both LSTM and CNN models seperately for my timeseries classification problem. My two models are as follows.

LSTM:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(25,3)))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

CNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(200, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(25,3)))
model.add(Conv1D(200, kernel_size=2))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I think LSTM and CNN has there unique characteristics and combining these two in my prediction will produce better results. However, I am struggling to find a suitable resource that suits my problem.

Is it possible to do this for my problem? If so how I can do it? Will it produce better results?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

### EDIT:

My problem setting is as follows. I have a dataset with about 5000 data points. Each data point has 3 time-series data that are exactly 25 in size. My labeled data is `1` or `0` (i.e. binary classification). More specifically my dataset looks as follows.

```
node, time-series1, time_series2, time_series3, Label
n1, [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2, ... 5.6, 8.8], [6.2, 5.2, 4.7, 3.2, ... 2.6, 1.8], [1.0, 2.8, 3.9, 4.1, ... 5.2, 8.6] …, 1
n2, [5.2, 4.5, 3.7, 2.2, ... 1.6, 0.8], [8.2, 7.5, 6.7, 5.2, ... 4.6, 1.8], …, [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2, ... 5.2, 8.5] 0
and so on.
```

I input these data to my LSTM and CNN models.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you're trying to solve. This is very much problem dependent

Comment: Do you have images in your data to leverage CNNs for or just 1d signals?

Comment: @thushv89 No, unfortunately I do not have images. It is all 1-d timeseries data. Would it be a problem?

Comment: You say that each data point has 3 time series,  does this not mean you have a multivariate (3D) time series for each datapoint? Or are the series of the nature that you can just add and create a single series form all 3?

Comment: @JimmyOnThePage Yes, you are correct. I have 3 seperate time-series data for each data point. I created a vector in a shape of (25,3) to input them to my models. :)

Comment: I see. I've seen this done. See this post for a start, to see how the base architecture will look: https://towardsdatascience.com/get-started-with-using-cnn-lstm-for-forecasting-6f0f4dde5826

Comment: Whether this will perform better than just a standalone LSTM or CNN with 1D convolutions will depend on your data I suppose; but the only reason I can see for combining the two will be if you are able to use a pretrained model for either of the architectures. (such as pretrained imagenet CNN's)

Comment: @JimmyOnThePage I saw this tutorial. However, it is bit different to what I am doing. They are doing timeseries forecasting while I am doing a timeseries classification. Please let me know if you have suggestions. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah but changing the architecture for a classification only requires changing the final layer and loss function (exactly as you've done in the question for your separate models), except if I am missing some complication here? (just skimmed through that article too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to just put one layer after another? This sounds pretty standard...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(200, kernel_size=3, activation = useSomething, input_shape=(25,3)))
model.add(LSTM(200))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Do you want to try the opposite?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(25,3)))
model.add(Conv1D(200, kernel_size=3, activation = useSomething))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Do you want a huge model?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(15, kernel_size=3, activation = useSomething, input_shape=(25,3)))
model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Conv1D(70, kernel_size=3, activation = useSomething))
............
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

---

Try many things:

- Conv, LSTM
- LSTM, Conv
- Conv, Conv, .., Conv, LSTM, ..., LSTM
- LSTM, LSTM, ..., Conv, Conv, ....
- C, L, C, L, C, L, ....
- L, C, L, C, L, C, ....
- C, C, L, L, C, C, ....

---

A two sided model?

```
inputs = Input((25,3))

side1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))(inputs) #200 total units
side2 = Conv1D(200, activation = 'tanh', padding = 'same')(inputs) #same activation 
                                                                   #same length

merged = Add()([side1, side2]) 
     #or Concatenate()([side1, side2]) if different number of units/channels/features

outputs = Conv1D(200)(merged)
outputs = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(outputs)
outputs = Dense(100)(outputs)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(outputs)

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: Thank you. I love the combinations of the models that you have proposed. I will try them :)

Comment: I have one quick question. If I want to add a dropout layer, where would you suggest me to put those in? Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: Just one? Not sure, before or after the `Dense(100)`. But I'd use a few Dropout layers spread around the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean like after every layer in the network?

Comment: It's possible, but maybe no. Usually I experiment a few options to see. I'd use dropouts if overfitting, does one dropout make it better? Then two?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The details that you provided were very useful and I will try to add the dropout layers as you have suggested :)

Comment: I am using the following model for my predictions `Conv1D, Conv1D, LSTM, LSTM, Dense`. I would like to know whether it is essential to perform `GlobalMaxPooling1D`  just after `Conv1D` or it is fine to use wthout a pooling layer as I have mentioned. I look forward to hearing from you. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at LSTNet, which does exactly that - https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.07015 and https://github.com/laiguokun/LSTNet